# Woocommerce web site 6-7 second pageloads

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress, woocommerce, pagespeed

I have a wordpress based ecommerce website with Woocommerce.

I use WP-Rocket Plugin for cache

I use CND

I use a Cloud dedicated server : 9CPU X 2GHZ 7GB Ram Apache

For cached page pageloads are very good it takes only 1-1.5 second. But uncached page it takes 6-7 seconds and this is a dynamic ecommerce website most pageloads are uncached. In website search and infinite scroll feature which came with my theme are same it takes 5-7 seconds. I try to change my hosting provider and try Kinsta which is a premium wordpress hosting but nothing has changed. What should i do for reducing this pageloads. When i click for a new category grey waiting icon in chrome takes 3-4 seconds and when it turn to blue it only takes 1-2 . I think main problem is this. I will add same screenshots cloud you please check it

[This is for unchached page.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PiG9P.jpg)

[This is for infinite scroll](https://i.stack.imgur.com/E7dS3.jpg)

[This is for in site search](https://i.stack.imgur.com/a5USB.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

There is very little detailed instructions I can give you based on the fact that this is a debugging project. However, I can provide you with some tools and advice.

The first thing you wan to do is eliminate that it is your hosting. A decent minimal hosting environment should be able to run WordPress and WooCommerce on the Storefront theme (https://wordpress.org/themes/storefront/) with times around 400-600ms with no caching. Better hosting can produce better times. So install that theme and disable ALL plugins except WooCommerce and check your TTFB times. If they are still high, then it is a hosting issue. It may or may not be resource allocation that can be fixed by adjusting the hosting environment. However, that's a different question.

Assuming that the TTFB times reach the target range of 400-600ms in that configuration, you can proceed to determine the cause of your slowdown.

First, enable all of the plugins you are using again except the caching plugin. Check your speed. It should go up some, but not too much. If you are back at the >5000ms then you can bet your issues are with one (or more) of the plugins. Turn them all off and then turn them on one at a time checking the speed after each activation. It is also possible that there is a conflict between plugins. If you find that plugins are your problem, then you should seek out new ones to replace that functionality or do custom development.

Next enable your desired theme. You should do this with all the plugins enabled in case there are dependencies. If this is the cause of your slowdown then you have a couple of options. One is to install some debugging plugins and try to determine if you can fix those issues in a child theme or to work with the theme developer to integrate changes. The second is to find another theme that will meet your needs. And lastly, you can build one yourself or do a child theme of Storefront.

Some good debugging plugins that can show where issues exist are:

Debug Bar - https://wordpress.org/plugins/debug-bar/ (there are additional plugins that add features to the main plugin as well)

Query Monitor - https://wordpress.org/plugins/query-monitor/ (best for database related issues)